# Why the instance on the google app engine is still alive even though there has never been an incoming request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

i work using google cloud platform. there seems to be something strange with basic scaling on my google app engine. referring to the [instance documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed), "Instances are created on demand to handle requests". But as you can see in the figure, there are 3 instances generated even though they don't have an incoming request. Even if there is a high demand request, it creates a new instance instead of using the 3 active instance

Then it should be based on the configuration that I have set, the instances will shutdown at 5 minutes idle. But seen in the figure the clock shows 09.15 and if it is calculated at the start time of each instance it should have exceeded 5 minutes. I rarely check the graph of this instance, but lately the services down often occurs due to the use of instances that are not optimal. Anyone know what's going on? thank you

[image]

[image: instance used]

Comment: Are you sure that the requests your application receives are not issuing any background activities that could keep the instances active?

Comment: I dont have any background thread on my apps. I already enable scheduler but there is no issue at least for 2 weeks ago. This is weird because some instance in my app engine will shut down if idle for a minutes but some other instance will experience issues like the 3 instances above

Comment: I see. You can always kill the instances yourself by running [gcloud app instances delete INSTANCE --service=SERVICE --version=VERSION](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/instances/delete). But for this type of issues I don't believe that SO will be the best place to get the answers, as debugging such type of issues will usually involve further debugging of the instances by [opening a case with support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases). You'd require to purchase a license though.